# GAE / Python / jinja2 / How to reference a subdirectory in join statement

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates, jinja2

I have a html file "listagem.html" in the subdirectory "static" of my root directory.
I want to use "listagem.html" as a templates for jinja2.

I tried these 3 join formulas:

First:

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    autoescape = True, 
    loader =  jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')))
```

Second:

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    autoescape = True, 
    loader =  jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/')))
```

Third:

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '/static')))
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('listagem.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

and received this error:

```
file not accessible: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppEngine\\MyAppRoot\\static\\listagem.html'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Tanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

You have probably added a `static_dir` url handler in you `app.yaml` file and have set you `static` directory (where you templates are) as a `static_dir`.

This makes your files unaccessible because [static files are not available in the application's file system](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers).

Remove `static_dir` from the `app.yaml`file and add a static-templates folder in your project folder.

Create a jinja environment as follows:

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')))
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked, to help others who see the question

Comment: Just to expand on this with something that seems obvious, but if a file is matched by a `skip_files` regex, you will also get the `IOError`. So, it can't be static and the path should not be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake.
1. in your appengine config file, you need same code like that:

```
application: yourapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css
- url: /img
  static_dir: static/img  
- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

look that "- url items"... this is for your static content( js css img )
for your html template, you need a subfolder template son of your root-app, in my case is myapp/template and inside put your template( templates content, html )

your main app look like that.
main.py

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'name': 'nombre',
            'verb': 'programando'
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))    

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```